# Can I use pg_config of other version of PostgreSQL?

Tags: centos, postgresql, installation

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 running on CentOS 7. I installed it from [PostgreSQL's](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.4/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos94-9.4-3.noarch.rpm) [repository](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.4/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/). And now I want to install ruby gem `pg`. But it fails, since it can't find `pg_config`.

Now then, `psql` works, and in the rpm file I can see:

```
$ rpm -q --scripts -p postgresql94-9.4.12-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm | egrep 'psql|pg_config'
/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/psql pgsql-psql /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql 940
...
```

So, it makes `psql` automatically available, but not `pg_config`. Is it by design or by accident? Should I install `posgresql` as well and use `pg_config` from PosgreSQL 9.2?

Comment: Can you run `locate pg_cofig`

Comment: Sure, the path is `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/README_rdoc.html#label-How+To+Install)

> You may need to specify the path to the 'pg_config' program installed with Postgres:
>
> ```
> gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>
> ```

So try this,

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Updated for things not previously mentioned, but also in [the docs](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/README_rdoc.html#label-How+To+Install).

> If you're installing via Bundler, you can provide compile hints like so:
>
> ```
> bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>
> ```

Comment: That wasn't the whole story. I simplified it a bit. The server is provisioned with `ansible`, and the site is deployed with `capistrano`. And I don't literally do `gem install pg`. I do `bundle`. And `bundle` doesn't take `--with-pg-config` option. Also, I'd prefer it if it was resolved while provisioning the server. And now that I think about it, I can just run `update-alternatives` for `pg_config`. What do you say?

Comment: @x-yuri updated =)

Comment: Why not do it during provisioning phase? When `ruby` is not yet installed? Like, run `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pg_config pgsql-pg_config /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config 940`? Additionally, I just discovered that `bundle pristine` doesn't work, despite having run `bundle config build.pg...`. But `bundle` does.

Comment: I don't think you understand what update-alternatives does. You may as well just ask if you can create a convoluted system of symlinks to resolve this issue of a ruby script not being able to find a file. Yes, you could do that assuming `find_executable` accepts symlinks. But it's not the route I would take.

Comment: I believe I do understand. And I'm not creating a convoluted system of symlinks. It already exists. And not a convoluted one probably. The way I see it, I just run a command that was supposed to run as part of PostgreSQL installation.

Comment: Also, consider that if you ever upgrade PostgreSQL you're going to have to pick which version of `pg_config` you want. And if you forget to pick it, it's going to point to the old version, because you're using that convoluted system. You now have to remember to run `update-alternatives` on a dist-upgrade (it's not bundled that way).

Comment: Let me elaborate on the idea. Provisioning sets up PostgreSQL and adds alternative for `pg_config` to the alternative system, if not already added. To update PostgreSQL I'd update host variable governing PostgreSQL version and provision the server. And it would automatically switch to newer `pg_config`, since the alternatives system works in automatic mode and newer alternative has higher priority (`950` for PostgreSQL 9.5) than the older one (`940` for PostgreSQL 9.4).

Comment: ...Regarding `dist-upgrade`, will it install `postgresql` package (official repository) even so no such package is installed? What is installed is, say, `postgresql94` package from PostgreSQL repository? Will it remove alternative for `pg_config` from the alternatives system? But more importantly, I think it's the issue with the package itself. It should add alternative for `pg_config` to the alternatives system along with alternatives for other utilities. And I'm in the process of conveying that to maintainers. So, hopefully, the problem will cease to exist in a while.

Comment: That depends on package pinning, and package bundling.

Comment: ...So, the problem is with the package, not with `ruby`. And is to be handled on "package's side." Or else it's the site that you make more convoluted. That's my take on it. `That depends on package pinning` I'm not going to pin anything. `and package bundling` Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You need a consultant or a teacher. I can't get you up to date in the comments.. This is taking way too much time. You want to play with a system that no one uses for good reason (`update-alternatives`). You're ignoring the docs. You don't understand how packaging or pinning works or how the database will be upgraded in your specific system. None of that stuff has anything to do with this question. The answer here is `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>` Take it from the authors that wrote the software. ;)

Comment: [Name calling](http://www.paulgraham.com/disagree.html)? A lot of baseless accusations. Regarding what can count as an argument, I have more experience with Debian systems. And there it's used a lot. I see 436 symlinks in `/etc/alternatives` on an arbitrary server. Well, that must have to do with it being developed in Debian community, then ported to CentOS. And that may indeed bring some issues. Although, I'm yet to find them. At least relevant to my case. Anyways, let's leave it at that. More of what I have to say [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9a2621122cf899605b8015ce1017be95).

Comment: I never called you names. I said you need a consultant or a teacher. Debian and Ubuntu don't use the default packaging of PostgreSQL. They wrap the whole thing in [clustering tools](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158507/2639). So you're `/usr/bin/pg_config` isn't even the real `pg_config`, and even on debian it doesn't touch `update-alternatives`. You're making all kinds of assumptions. You want to use `update-alternatives`, but why? As I said a long time ago *"I don't think you understand what update-alternatives does."*

Comment: If you want to remember to run `update-alternatives`, and run it when you're building for the next version of PostgreSQL -- then by all means try that method. I don't want to do that. I want my build to ask me which version on my system it wants to build against. That's the default. That's what the authors suggest. That's `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>`

Comment: What you say surely makes sense when you've got multiple versions of PostgreSQL running on a server. Then I'd avoid using `update-alternatives` as well. But then again, I don't have that, and hopefully won't. But it may explain why package maintainers don't add alternative for `pg_config`. They aim for a more general case with multiple instances on a server. As such that's not a mistake on their part. They won't fix it. Assuming my assumption is right, it probably makes sense to go with the flow. Gotta think it over. Thanks for sharing your thoughts :)

Comment: Nothing is supported indefinitely. And if you're not planning to have two versions on the server, just think in five years when you *have* to upgrade if you want to be tracking down symlink problems when `build.pg` is compiling your gem for your new PostgreSQL 12.6 against PostgreSQL 9.4, simply because it doesn't know any better. =)